# Upload csv files from C: drive path into R Programming

Tags: r, csv, directory, upload

I am new to R programming and starting a case study, Bellabeat for Google Capstone. I am in the process of accessing .csv files. I tried spreadsheets (too large), SQL (timestamp parsing error) and decided to move onto R programming to clean and do analysis.

I cannot seem to access my laptop drive correctly to read in the files. I have tried loading different libraries, packages, and numerous attempts with different syntax. I'm stumped because the path makes sense to me, but I keep getting errors.

Efforts:
Install Packages:

```
##install.packages("tidyverse")
##install.packages("janitor")
##install.packages("dplyr")
##install.packages("stringr")

##install.packages("Posit.io.R") (not available in my version)

##library(tidyverse)
##library(janitor)
##library(dplyr)
##library(stringr)
##library(readr)
##library(lubridate)

##library(Posit.io.R) (not available)

## Set up working directory to upload csv files.

    ##setwd("C:/Users/Dmanc/OneDrive/Desktop/Google iCloud/Capstone - Study/Bellabeat/Dataset csv files")

## Example:  my_data <- read_csv("my_data.csv")
## Read csv file and output it to new variable file name

    ##dailyActivity <- read_csv("C:/Users/Dmanc/OneDrive/Desktop/Google iCloud/Capstone - Study/Bellabeat/Dataset csv files/dailyActivity_merged.csv")

    ##dailyActivity <- read_csv("C:\Users\Dmanc\OneDrive\Desktop\Google iCloud\Capstone - Study\Bellabeat\Dataset csv files", dailyActivity_merged.csv")
                          
    ##upload_csv("dailyActivity_merged.csv", "dailyActivity")

    ##dailyActivity <- import_csv("dailyActivity_merged.csv")

    ##dir.create("C:/Users/Dmanc/OneDrive/Desktop/Google iCloud/Capstone - Study/Bellabeat/Dataset csv files")

##> dailyActivity <- read_csv("C:/Users/Dmanc/OneDrive/Desktop/Google iCloud/Capstone - ## Study/Bellabeat/Dataset csv files/dailyActivity_merged.csv")
## Error: 'C:/Users/Dmanc/OneDrive/Desktop/Google iCloud/Capstone - Study/Bellabeat/Dataset csv ## files/dailyActivity_merged.csv' does not exist.
```

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured it out! I was confused at first about the upload in the Files location in Posit. I thought it meant to upload files from R to another location, but I learned I can upload files from my hard drive too with tool too! :)